# In ASP.net MVC, what's the right way to handoff to another controller and then return back to the original controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

(Using ASP.NET MVC, C#, fairly new to the environment)

I have a controller that creates a row in a table, say a *person*, and then another controller that creates another row in another table that creates something that has a one to many relationship with the other table e.g. a *course* that contains many people.

When I create a new course in my web application, I want to be able to link to adding a person to the course, either an existing person or a new person. So I link from the course detail controller to the person controller. Then I want it to remember where it came from so I could go back to the course page and show the newly added people.

In the spirit of DRY, I wouldn't want to make a separate controller and view for creating a person within the course class. What's the proper way to get the person controller to return to the course controller when it's finished? Some kind of delegate? In iOS (which I am more used to) you might accomplish this by loading in the view modally and then assigning a delegate, and then calling the delegate if it exists and dismissing the view. Is there anything analogous here?

Thanks

Comment: `CourseController` should be responsible for creating, editing and viewing `Course`s so adding a `Person` to a `Course` should be the responsibility of `CourseController`. If your wanting to create a new `Person` so you can then assign them to a `Course` that would be the responsibility of the `PersonController`, in which case you could pass an optional `CourseID` to the method, render its value in the view and on postback, get the value and `return RedirectToAction("Edit", Course", new { ID = CourseID });

Answer (score 2):

In the TRUE spirit of DRY, wouldn't you want to encapsulate each of your creation methods in a respective DAL and then call them directly from your controllers as they are required?  It seems as if you are embedded data access and business logic layers into your controllers.  I know this is a popular approach in tutorials and simple applications, but I believe it causes long term issues (such as the issues you are running into now).  My recommendation is to move your business logic back a layer and save yourself a controller redirect.

EDIT:

You can handle the CRUD data access on your entity models at a point that is deeper in your application than your controllers.  In fact, many people would argue that to do so is correct separation of concerns.  What I am suggesting is building a Data Access Layer that modifies your entity objects a layer removed from your controllers.  That way your data access does not bloat your controller and you can call multiple types of data access methods from various controllers.

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. The data access is handled with entity models, so they can be modified anywhere. Are you saying I should be creating all the different CRUD views etc in a single controller?